# Jquery drag and drop not working properly due to overflow property of css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I downloaded the jquery plugin from [Jquery Drag and Drop](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert)

The code are working fine.. But in my design, i have a specific area for the draggable items, so i set the area using following css:-

```
.overflow_test {
           width:500px;
          float:left;
          overflow:auto;
          height:200px;
}
```

Now the items are scrollable within a fixed area. But when i drag an item from item section its not working properly means function works but the item doesnt show up..

Here's my demo [demo](http://www.apprs.com/test/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because when using drag and drop, the draggable item stays in the same DOM place (i.e. inside the same div), only its position is changed. Even if you remove the overflow:auto setting, technically the dragged item will stay inside the original DIV.

Some of the things you can do:
If you don't need the horizontal scrollbar, then you can only enable the vertical scrollbar by setting overflow-y to auto and overflow-x to resize or hidden, based on what you need.

If you need both scrollbars, you can consider appending the corresponding draggable item to the droppable after a succesful drop, removing it from the original DIV.

Comment: I need only vertical scrollbar. I did overflow-y as auto and overflow-x to hidden. The item is dropped but it doesn't show up in droped box. Any idea

Comment: Can you please revert the demo (including JS) to the original state, so I can check it?